# VBA : How to set the value to a textarea in an object type of internetexplorer.application

Tags: vba, textarea

I've been trying to write some text into a textarea element of an aspnet form using the object internetexplorer.application in a macro using VBA

When I add a watch to the object after setting the "Value" attribute, i get the text that i am setting (using a MsgBox), but the browser doesnot seem to get the text when i submit it.

Im using IE 8.0.6001  and Office 2003.

Any help / comment will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub Test2()

Dim Title As String
Dim Comments As String



Set wb = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
wb.navigate2 "http://tudrintra01/ads/Lists/Tasks1/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fads%2FLists%2FTasks1&ContentTypeId=0x01030062FE73EDFA7DA644A27CE244EA983DA4&Source=http%3A%2F%2Ftudrintra01%2Fads%2FLists%2FTasks1%2FMyItems%2Easpx" 

wb.Visible = True

 Title = "TITULO PRUEBA"
 Comments = COMENTARIO PRUEBA" '"Comentario"


Do Until wb.readyState = 4 ' wait for page to load
 DoEvents
 Loop

    'Si el objeto es el Titulo del task
    wb.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_m_g_c0644918_3730_4e2c_8434_7b760939e3d4_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = Title

    'Si el objeto es el Comment
    wb.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_m_g_c0644918_3730_4e2c_8434_7b760939e3d4_ctl00_ctl04_ctl14_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = Comments



    ' Clean up
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any event handlers on the elements you are adding the text to or on whichever control you use to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

You have not got an answer for days, so I comment on your question now. I successfully automated IE via the WebBrowser object, not via an Internetexplorer.Application object. Webbrowser will not open an IE application instance but just a "document window" in a Webbrowser control in a form in your Access application. So if you don't use Access or for some other reason this might not be a valuable hint for you.

This is not an answer to your question, that's why I waited some time to give my comment, but it's my best comment and I did everything possible with the DOM model through a wb object and never experienced a problem like yours that I could not solve. So you might want to try and rewrite your sub to using a Webbrowser.